# How to change numbers to date in a composite formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I wanted the output **Today's date: 04 January 2021** and used the formula `="Today's date: "& TODAY()` but the output was **Today's date: 44200**. How do I change this to date format?

I tried the following:

1. Change the cell format using Home>> Number>> General to Date
2. Using the text to columns option Data>> Data tools>> Text to columns
3. Using the format cells and setting the format type as "dd-mm-yyyy". I know that gives output as something like 04-01-2021 but at least that would be an improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with TEXT:

```
="Today's date: "& TEXT(TODAY(),"DD MMMM YYYY")
```

[image]